# Interpreting database values as times and integers

Tags: haskell, error-handling, database

I am working through Chapter 10 of Haskell Programming from First Principles.

I've gotten the code to work, but I am uneasy about the fact that a few of my functions - namely, `extractUTCTime` and `extractInteger` - are not total functions. There is valid input for which those functions are *bottom*. I've added the code below, but I was wondering what strategies are available for making `extractUTCTime` and `extractInteger` safe. (One strategy that I do know of is changing the type signature of these functions so that they return a value of type `Maybe`: `extractUTCTime :: DatabaseItem -> Maybe UTCTime`. I was wondering if there was anything else that can be done).

```
import Data.Time

data DatabaseItem = DbString String | DbNumber Integer | DbDate UTCTime deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

theDatabase :: [DatabaseItem]
theDatabase = [DbDate (UTCTime (fromGregorian 1911 5 1) (secondsToDiffTime 34123)), DbNumber 9001, DbString "Hello, world!", DbDate (UTCTime (fromGregorian 1921 5 1) (secondsToDiffTime 34123))]

filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate [] = []
filterDbDate dataBase = [extractUTCTime item | item <- dataBase, isDbDate item]

isDbDate :: DatabaseItem -> Bool
isDbDate (DbDate _) = True
isDbDate _          = False

extractUTCTime :: DatabaseItem -> UTCTime
extractUTCTime (DbDate utcData) = utcData

filterDbNumber :: [DatabaseItem] -> [Integer]
filterDbNumber [] = []
filterDbNumber dataBase = [extractInteger item | item <- dataBase, isDbNumber item]

extractInteger :: DatabaseItem -> Integer
extractInteger (DbNumber int) = int

isDbNumber :: DatabaseItem -> Bool
isDbNumber (DbNumber _) = True
isDbNumber _ = False

mostRecent :: [DatabaseItem] -> UTCTime
mostRecent dataBase = foldr max y ys
                where dates = filterDbDate dataBase
                      y     = head dates
                      ys    = tail dates

sumDb :: [DatabaseItem] -> Integer
sumDb dataBase = foldr (+) 0 dbNumbers
                 where dbNumbers = filterDbNumber dataBase

avgDb :: [DatabaseItem] -> Double
avgDb dataBase = dividend / divisor
                 where dividend = fromIntegral $ sumDb dataBase
                       divisor = fromIntegral $ length $ filterDbNumber dataBase
```

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if there was anything else that can be done

Well, morally, no. You can either return a nullable value (`Maybe UTCTime`) or lie (`read "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" :: UTCTime`) but you can't turn a `DbNumber 1 :: DatabaseItem` into a `UTCTime` both unconditionally and truthfully.

The good news is, if you hit on the right set of higher-order functions you don't need to. `Maybe` values are very easy to work with when you know the extra tools available in [`Data.Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html).

Taking as a whole this set of functions related to dates—

```
filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate [] = []
filterDbDate dataBase = [extractUTCTime item | item <- dataBase, isDbDate item]

isDbDate :: DatabaseItem -> Bool
isDbDate (DbDate _) = True
isDbDate _          = False

extractUTCTime :: DatabaseItem -> UTCTime
extractUTCTime (DbDate utcData) = utcData

mostRecent :: [DatabaseItem] -> UTCTime
mostRecent dataBase = foldr max y ys
                where dates = filterDbDate dataBase
                      y     = head dates
                      ys    = tail dates
```

We'll begin by throwing out `isDbDate` and `extractUTCTime` and writing the `DatabaseItem -> Maybe UTCTime` function you avoided.

```
dbDate :: DatabaseItem -> Maybe UTCTime
dbDate (DbDate utc) = Just utc
dbDate _            = Nothing
```

Now pulling from `Data.Maybe`, we'll replace `filterDbDate` with an equivalent code fragment that utilizes `mapMaybe`.

```
-- filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
-- filterDbDate db =
     mapMaybe dbDate db
```

We can use that definition in `mostRecent`, a function from the standard Prelude, and point free style to achieve a one liner that more than just being clever, emphasizes the power of abstraction in producing concise code that will be instantly comprehensible to other Haskell programmers.

```
mostRecent :: [DatabaseItem] -> UTCTime
mostRecent = maximum . mapMaybe dbDate
```

`mostRecent` still commits the sin of using a partial function though, `maximum` throws an exception (much like your use of `head` and `tail` did before) when the filtered list is empty. Until such time as partial functions are excised from `base` (and O, do we all lust for and fear such a tumultuous day) you should familiarize yourself with the `safe` package, which has no dependencies besides `base`, and provides many alternatives to the partial functions we all know and love.

```
import Safe.Foldable (maximumMay)

mostRecent :: [DatabaseItem] -> Maybe UTCTime
mostRecent = maximumMay . mapMaybe dbDate
```

Comment: Rowan - thank you very much for such a great explanation. As a beginner, I haven't fully groked the code, but I'll be coming back to it when we get to that part of the book. I also really appreciate your first paragraph. Thank you!